# Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found. 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, summernote

I keep having this error when I try to add a post.
It says,

**"Reverse for 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' not found. 'django_summernote-upload_attachment' is not a valid view function or pattern name."**

I know this is not a matter of adding "path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')" because I've already done that.

models.py

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget

CATEGORY = (
    ("Beginner", "Beginner"),
    ("Intermediate", "Intermediate"),
    ("Advanced", "Advanced"),
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course_posts')
    content = models.TextField()
    # content = models.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CATEGORY, default="Beginner")

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```html
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'course_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('course/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='course'),
    path('course/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='course_posts'),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('editor/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    """
    Return all posts that are with status 1 (published) and order from the latest one.
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    template_name = 'course.html'


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'course_post.html'


def courses(request):
    return render(request, 'course.html', {'navbar': 'courses'})
```

I tried adding a jpg file as a attachment, and that works. It's just the "add post" function that I have an error with.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how my URLs look like and it is working well, but before I was getting the same error and I fixed it by adding those two paths **summernote** and **editor**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='admin/login/', permanent=False), name='/'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('editor/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the pattern with name **'django_summernote-upload_attachment'** is not present in your urlpatterns variable. Looking at the `urls.py` file from this package (see https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/main/django_summernote/urls.py) we can see that the corresponding pattern is added only if the `'disable_attachment'` key value for the config is `False`.

Check your `settings.py` file and look for the `SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG` variable. There you should see the `'disable_attachment'` key. Make sure that its value is set to `False` (see https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote#options). Otherwise, the `urlpattern` that Django is trying to reach won't be registered and you will get the error that you posted.

As a side note, take care with the `urls.py` file and the patterns included there because you are including the same set of patterns in two different endpoints:

```py
 path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')), # using include('django_summernote.urls')
 path('editor/', include('django_summernote.urls')) # using include('django_summernote.urls') once again
```

This can cause redirection problems if the patterns included have the same naming. Removing one of these two patterns will do the job, just take it into account across your other files!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I just fixed it  For me, the problem wasn't "disable_attachment" key; I added "path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls'))," to the main app's urls.py, not the urls.py for the particular app(Post). That solved the problem. Thanks for your input!